# Unable to get JSON data in _POST variable in php

Tags: php, json, curl, http-post

I'm using this curl command to send json data to a php webservice, but i'm not getting anything in the $_POST variable.

Here is the curl command

```
 curl -X POST -i -H "Content-type: application/json" -c cookies.txt -X POST http://192.168.2.127:8888/json.php -d '{"age":"234","password":"password"}'
```

and here is the php code.

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');

var_dump($_POST);
$return_arr = array();
$age = $_POST['age'];
$ageInt = intval($_POST['age']);
$return_arr['age1'] = $age;
var_dump($_POST);
$return_arr['age2'] = $ageInt;
echo json_encode($return_arr);
?>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Once try this

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d  '{"age":"21343","password":"password"}' http://192.168.2.127:8888/json.php
```

Comment: curl -X POST -d '{"age":"21343","password":"password"}' http://192.168.2.127:8888/json.php --header "Content-Type:application/json"

Tried this, but to no avail

Comment: still no luck, i don't if its relevant or not, but i'm working on a mac